# How to Auto Increment a Date Field in an Access Table

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, auto-increment

I have an Access table with 3 columns: an AutoNumber "WeeklyID", a fgn key "CampaignID", and a date field "WeekEnded". 
[It looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Tjgz.png)
What I need to accomplish is a method to automatically add 7 days to the date field for each record sharing the same CampaignID.

So, if there are 3 records with the same Campaign ID and the date associated with the first record is 4/1/2016, I want the date on the second record to be 4/8/2016, and the date on the third record to be 4/15/2016.

I am not sure if this is possible to accomplish via the DateAdd function in Access, so I'm wondering if there is any VBA that can get the job done?

Comment: @GordThompson  Yes, I'm on Access 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a one-time thing then it's probably easiest just to take Gustav's suggestion and create a VBA routine that loops through a `DAO.Recordset` to update the dates. However, since you're using Access_2013 I thought I'd mention another approach: an event driven [Data Macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200).

If you define the following Before Change data macro on the table

[image: BeforeChange.png]

then any time you add a new row for an existing [CampaignID] with a `NULL` [WeekEnded] column the data macro will populate [WeekEnded] with the value for the following week.

If you create the macro on an existing table and want to update the existing rows then you could simply run the UPDATE query

```sql
UPDATE TheTable SET CampaignID = CampaignID WHERE WeekEnded IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hey Gord, Thanks for the response. I am trying to implement your solution right now. But is it appears as though the SetField function in Access 2013 must be used within a createrecord or editrecord data block. How would the macro change in order to accommodate this?

Comment: @TryingtoLearn - Are you trying to use it in a "Before Change" macro or one of the "After ..." ones?

Comment: Currently trying with an After Insert & will also try with After Update

Comment: That's why it's not working. It needs to be in the Before Change macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the recordset picking a date when found and using DateAdd to add and store a week for each of the subsequent records with the same ID - until a new ID and date is found. And so on.